# Is there a possibility to find the genes a fastq Sequences belongs to (STAR)?

Tags: bioinformatics

**I use STAR aligner to analyze fastq files.
The fastq files look like this:**

@B091JABXX110402:6:1203:12620:102907
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCT
+
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHG
@B091JABXX110402:6:2103:7806:26781
AGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTT
+
HHFHFGGGGGHHHHHFBFFFGGGGFFFFCFEEEE@E
@B091JABXX110402:6:2206:10174:15638
TAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCC
+
FEFGGFGGGGGGDEGGDGDGGGGFGGFGFGGGBEGG

...

**After analyzing with Star i get a file named ReadsPerGene.out.tab**

ENSG00000223972.5     0    0        0
ENSG00000227232.5     0    0        0
ENSG00000278267.1     0    0        0
ENSG00000186092.6     1    0        1
ENSG00000238009.6     3    0        3
ENSG00000239945.1     0    0        0

On the left side I get the genname and on the right side how many sequences belong to. Now I want to know which sequence from my fastq file belongs to which genname. So i can say AACCCC.. belongs to gene ENSG003..

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to use something like `bedtools intersect` which will make a tabular output connecting the query file (e.g. the gene coordinates in BED format) with the reads in the BAM file. But, why do you need that, there might be a better way of answering the question you have. In any case you better ask these types of questions at biostars.org where the bioinformatics audiance is much larger than here.